# How to get rid of "TypeError: Unable to require file: src/world/world.d.ts" error in Cucumber?

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I am building a repository with cucumber-selenium in typescript. I want to create a world declaration in a file

```
// src/world/world.d.ts

import { Driver } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome'
import { ICreateAttachment, ICreateLog } from '@cucumber/cucumber'

declare module '@cucumber/cucumber' {
  interface IWorld {
    readonly attach: ICreateAttachment
    readonly log: ICreateLog
    readonly parameters: unknown
    driver: Driver
  }
}
```

But when I run the test with `cucumber-js` flags

```
  'features/**/*.feature',
  '--require-module ts-node/register',
  '--require src/world/customWorld.ts',
  '--require src/**/*.ts',
  '-f json:report/cucumber_report.json',
  '-f progress-bar'
```

And tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2019",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noEmit": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "ts-node": {
      "files": true
    }
  }
```

I get

```
TypeError: Unable to require file: src/world/world.d.ts
This is usually the result of a faulty configuration or import. Make sure there is a `.js`, `.json` or other executable extension with loader attached before `ts-node` available.
```

Using versions

```
"@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.3.2",
"ts-node": "^10.7.0",
"typescript": "^4.5.5"
```

The code compiles, and runs as expected. Even VSCode Intellisense works fine - it's just that this error at the top of every script is pretty annoying. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the `--require src/**/*.ts` line in `cucumber.js`. Declaration files `.d.ts` should NOT be required. I have updated refactored the declaration from `src` to `declarations`, and the error is gone